# "Stack overflow" error when changing filename in a repeat loop with applescript

Tags: applescript, stack-overflow

As far as I can tell the standard applescript code for changing filenames is:

```
set name of my_file to "New_Name"
```

But when I use this inside a repeat loop (called by a folder action) I get a "Stack overflow" error.  Here's the full code:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    try
        repeat with this_item in these_items
            set name of this_item to "New_Name"
        end repeat

    on error error_message number error_number
        display dialog error_message buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1
    end try
end adding folder items to
```

Has anyone come across this problem?  Might it have anything to do with Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "System Events" to set name of this_item to "New_Name"
```